# Error in objective-c: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5f3ffff8)

Tags: objective-c, macos, runtime-error, sprite-kit

I made a simple mac application in Xcode 5 using objective-c / SpriteKit, and when I run the application, it crashes and produces the error when it gets to a part of the code. The error is: `Error in objective-c: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5f3ffff8)`

I know that there are many duplicates of this error on stack overflow, but from what I can gather, every instance is varied and the solution is only relevant to that example.

This is the code segment where the error is displayed in my code. (This exact same code works perfectly fine in other sections of my code though):

```
-(void)singlePlayer {
double delayInSeconds = 1;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC)); 
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{ //ERROR appears here
    SKNode *orbRoot = [self childNodeWithName:@"//ORB_ROOT"];
    NSArray *allOrbs = [orbRoot children];
    checkAccuracy = FALSE;
    for(SKNode *eachOrb in allOrbs) {
        if([eachOrb position].y >= 70 && [eachOrb position].y <= 130) {
            int randomNumber = arc4random()%3+1;
            switch (randomNumber) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // Shields
                    [orbOutline2 removeFromParent];
                    delayLargeOutline2 = TRUE;
                    xPos = 900;
                    yPos = 100;
                    CGPoint location = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos);
                    orbOutline2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"shoot.rhythm orb outline"];
                    orbOutline2.position = location;
                    orbOutline2.scale = 0.1;
                    [self addChild:orbOutline2];

                    [player2Feedback removeFromParent];
                    [self addChild:[self player2FeedbackNode:@"Shields!"]];
                    delayPlayer2Feedback = TRUE;

                    player2Shooting = FALSE;
                    player2Shield = TRUE;
                    player2Reloading = FALSE;
                    player2Idle = FALSE;

                    break;
                case 2:
                    //Shoot
                    if (player2Ammo > 0) {
                        [orbOutline2 removeFromParent];
                        delayLargeOutline2 = TRUE;
                        xPos = 900;
                        yPos = 100;
                        CGPoint location = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos);
                        orbOutline2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"shoot.rhythm orb outline"];
                        orbOutline2.position = location;
                        orbOutline2.scale = 0.1;
                        [self addChild:orbOutline2];

                        [player2Sprite removeFromParent];
                        delayShootingPlayer2 = TRUE;
                        [self addChild:[self player2SpriteNode:@"player2Shoot"]];
                        [self addChild:[self player2BulletNode]];
                        player2Shooting = TRUE;
                        player2Shield = FALSE;
                        player2Reloading = FALSE;
                        player2Idle = FALSE;
                    }
                    else {
                        [player2Feedback removeFromParent];
                        [self addChild:[self player2FeedbackNode:@"No Ammo!"]];
                        delayPlayer2Feedback = TRUE;
                        player2Health--;
                    }

                    break;
                case 3:
                    //Reload
                    player2Ammo++;
                    [orbOutline2 removeFromParent];
                    delayLargeOutline2 = TRUE;
                    xPos = 900;
                    yPos = 100;
                    location = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos);
                    orbOutline2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"shoot.rhythm orb outline"];
                    orbOutline2.position = location;
                    orbOutline2.scale = 0.1;
                    [self addChild:orbOutline2];

                    [player2Feedback removeFromParent];
                    [self addChild:[self player2FeedbackNode:@"Reloading!"]];
                    delayPlayer2Feedback = TRUE;

                    player2Shooting = FALSE;
                    player2Shield = FALSE;
                    player2Reloading = TRUE;
                    player2Idle = FALSE;

                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"Error with AI");
                    break;
            }
            [eachOrb removeFromParent];
        }
    }

});
[self singlePlayer];

}
```

Looking at other errors of this same kind on stack overflow, it seems that generally the error it self is not actually where the program stops at, so if to find a solution you need to see the full code, it is available here: (didn't want to put it all in here, might be a bit too long to scroll through) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/23672cffde9964ece16e#file-gistfile1-m-L1259

(The error was in line `1259` in the github link, and in the code above it was in the fourth line where it says `//ERROR appears here`.

Thank you, and if you need any more information please ask, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to put your code in a gist. http://gist.github.com. The bee txt site screws up code by escaping some characters

Comment: on which line does it signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: don't use dispatch_async for timed stuff in Sprite Kit, use the scene's update: method to schedule tasks. Otherwise you can hardly prevent this code from running after having changed scenes but before the block executed, and the block will also execute while the game is paused. Plus the block retaining any object in scope that you're using may prevent some objects from being deallocated timely.

Answer (score 1):

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2**

In gerenal equates to **the pointer is corrupt**, which can happen for a number of reasons:

- The pointer wasn't initialized properly.
- The pointer was overwritten (possibly because the bounds of an array were overstepped).
- The pointer is part of an object that was cast incorrectly.

In your code try using dispatch_after like:

```
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
```

Comment: sorry adding in (void) didn't seem to work, I still get the same error